# Adding Value to each object from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a small game where you have a deck of cards, two players get random half of the deck. Each time they play a card, then the system compares strengths of these hands. In the end, the player who had more wins (each one is 1 point) wins. Simple.
For example:
2♣ should have value 1
3♣ should have value 2

so the players see:
Player One: 2♣
Player Two: 3♣
Player Two wins

I am not sure how exactly add those values (like 3♣ value 2) for each string In deck_of_cards

```
import random
deck_of_cards = ["2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "Q♣", "K♣", "A♣"]
deck_of_cards = list(deck_of_cards)
hand_size = len((deck_of_cards))//2
player_one = random.sample(deck_of_cards, hand_size)
player_two = set(deck_of_cards) - set(player_one)
player_two = list(player_two)
print(player_one[2])
print(player_two[2])
if player_one > player_two:
   print("Player One Won")
else:
   print("Player Two Won")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `index` of each *Card* item in the `deck_of_cards` list (incremented by one):

```python
value = deck_of_cards.index("2♣") + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood your question correctly then you just need a deck_value list from `1 to 13` which will be useful for iterating over the `player_one` and `player_two` list to and adding the values of each card

```
import random
deck_of_cards = ["2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "Q♣", "K♣", "A♣"]
deck_values = [i for i in range(1,14)]
hand_size = len((deck_of_cards))//2
player_one = random.sample(deck_of_cards, hand_size)
player_two = list(set(deck_of_cards) - set(player_one))
m1,m2=0,0
for i in player_one:
    m1+=deck_values[deck_of_cards.index(i)]
for j in player_two:
    m2+=deck_values[deck_of_cards.index(j)]
if m1>m2:
   print("Player One Won")
else:
   print("Player Two Won")
```